# Is RxJava useful with Tomcat and Myql Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, rx-java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I have seen a few projects where developers are using RxJava with Tomcat and Mysql on Spring Boot.

As per my knowledge:

1. The main advantage of reactive streams is that it only creates a single thread per multiple requests, and hence database connection should also be non-blocking.
2. Tomcat creates threads per request.
3. Spring Data Jpa is blocking.

I know that there are libraries for non-blocking Relational databases (Like r2dbc).

So, I am specifically confused about the tomcat and RxJava benefits.

I would like to know the benefits of RxJava for the following scenarios:

1. Rest Api on tomcat with Spring data JPA (Mysql).
2. Rest Api on tomcat with R2dbc (MySql).

Thanks.

Comment: On tomcat the only benefit you have in either scenario is the use of the async servlet API, nothing more, nothing less. If you want full blown reactive you have to use one of the reactive implementations like Netty.

Comment: So you mean it will use asyncSupported=true [link] (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/servlets012.htm) internally? Will it also work with Spring Rest Library? Like @GetMapping public Single<String> getApi(){} ?

Comment: And with async servlet API, The threads will be created but it won't sit idle. right?

Comment: The request and response are handled by different threads, so the request handling thread is freed up quite quickly and a new thread is acquired to handle the response when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Benefits of Spring MVC and JPA (blocking), linear, easy to write and debug code. Slow clients may be slowing your app down.

Reactive Spring:
Small pool of threads handling many more requests - less memory consumed.
Downside: Takes time to start thinking 'reactively'.

More:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-async-vs-webflux

Also:
https://dzone.com/articles/micronaut-mastery-using-reactor-mono-and-flux
If you rest API doesn't always go to the database you could benefit from that approach.

Comment: Hi, I know the pros and cons of reactive but want to know the advantages of using rxjava with Tomcat. The links do not explain this. Thanks

Comment: Looking at this doc: 
https://spring.getdocs.org/en-US/spring-framework-docs/docs/spring-web-reactive/webflux/webflux-new-framework.html
I understand Tomcat supports reactive programming and if you have non blocking database lib you benefit form the fully reactive stack.